# Include template from another directory

Tags: go

In **templates\index.gohtml** I am using this code:

```
{{template "header"}}
<h1>INDEX</h1>
{{template "nav"}}

<form action="/apply" method="post">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I am getting the error:

> html/template:index.gohtml:3:11: no such template "nav"

I guess, this is because `nav` is defined in **templates\includes\nav.gohtml**. If so, I don't know why I am not getting the same error for `header`, since it's in the same directory.

my main.go looks like this:

```
func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Call ParseGlob on the includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are only parsing files in the templates folder.
If you change this line

```
tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
```

to this

```
tpl = template.Must(template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml")).ParseGlob("templates/includes/*.gohtml"))
```

it will parse the files in the templates folder, then parse the files in the templates/includes folder adding them to the existing parsed templates.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!